# Mouse keeps flouncing when I try to edit an object

Tags: edit-mode

I'm trying to edit and object and the mouse (I'm using a trackpad on a macbook pro) literally flounces: if I try to grab an object I may move the mouse for many blender units, but the object doesn't move... at a certain point if I keep moving the mouse the object moves but too fast. It literally moves at steps, the movement is not continuous. I [registered a video](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=768CF89E7CF13325!5477&authkey=!AHq7TYLMnoJa2_8&ithint=video%2Cmov) to make this clear. In the video I press G to grab the object, and like you can see the movement is not continuous, but it just makes a huge step after that I dragged the mouse for a while.

If I create a new project I don't have this problem anymore, it seems like there's something wrong with my project settings or my objects.

Comment: ...huh... "flouncing" *is* a real word...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "snap to grid" turned on. Click the little magnet button next to the Proportional Editing settings, and that will turn off snapping. You can use the pull-down menu next to the magnet to choose what element to use for snapping.